# google microbenchmarking cpu scaling warning

Tags: c++, microbenchmark

When I run the google [benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark) I get a **WARNING** saying that cpu scaling is enabled. Is that a feature that I can toggle at build via flags or at runtime via arguments or is it a system setting?

Comment: It depends on what CPU and platform you are using, but if it's an x86 PC then you can usually turn it off in the BIOS. On Linux there are also typically CPU governors than you can use to control scaling etc.

Answer (score 27):

As stated in [google benchmark documentation](https://github.com/google/benchmark#benchmark), to [disable CPU scaling](https://github.com/google/benchmark/blob/main/docs/user_guide.md#disabling-cpu-frequency-scaling) use `cpupower` tool.

```
sudo cpupower frequency-set --governor performance
./mybench
sudo cpupower frequency-set --governor powersave
```

Comment: In ubuntu the necessary tools can be installed with `sudo apt install linux-tools-common cpupower`.

Answer (score 0):

To change your CPU mode (governor), you should become root or use sudo, then one of `powersave` or `performance` should be echo in the file `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor`.

So, let’s say we want to switch from powersave mode to performance mode, we will do:

```
sudo sh -c "echo performance | tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor"
```

And if we want to switch back to powersave mode, we will do:

```
sudo sh -c "echo powersave | tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor"
```

And to get our current CPU mode, we will type:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
```